# does is affect NN training accuracy if the color format of images is BGR not RGB?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, training-data, image-formats

I'm training Neural Network with ImageNet dataset and I noticed that images are in BGR color format when I read them using OpenCV function `cv2.imread()`, so does is affect training accuracy?, if yes then how can I change it to RGB in pytorch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not affect your NN's accuracy, in general. However, if you are using a pre-trained CNN, then it likely expects RGB images as input, and will not do as well on BGR images initially and will have to re-learn its weights for BGR.

You can convert BGR to RGB using `cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`.

You can also consider the following alternatives for reading images:

- `torchvision.io.read_image(path)` (https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/io.html#image)
- `torch.from_numpy(np.array(PIL.Image.open(path)))`
- `torchvision.transforms.functional.pil_to_tensor(PIL.Image.open(path))` (https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.pil_to_tensor)

Comment: thanks, but is there any function to apply BGR_TO_RGB inside pytorch.transforms, because I am reading the data using dataloader class.

Comment: If your Dataset uses OpenCV for reading image files and you do not want to change it, you can use the `Lambda` transform to define a custom transform that applies `cv2.cvtColor`.